# how to solve 'range() integer end argument expected, got float'?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting the following error in the cnn_utils.py file when doing Coursera CNN example. I did everything I needed to convert the float to the int, but did not get the result. Please help me

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-ddfc1f084c11> in <module>()
----> 1 _, _, parameters = model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test)

<ipython-input-12-a206d32574f3> in model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, 
learning_rate, num_epochs, minibatch_size, print_cost)
 36             num_minibatches = int(m / minibatch_size) # number of 
minibatches of size minibatch_size in the train set
 37             seed = seed + 1
---> 38             minibatches = random_mini_batches(X_train, Y_train, 
minibatch_size, seed)
 39 
 40             for minibatch in minibatches:

/root/sharedfolder/cnn_utils.py in random_mini_batches(X, Y, mini_batch_size, seed)
 49     # Step 2: Partition (shuffled_X, shuffled_Y). Minus the end case.
 50     num_complete_minibatches = math.floor(m/mini_batch_size) # number of 
mini batches of size mini_batch_size in your partitionning
---> 51     for k in range(0, num_complete_minibatches):
 52         mini_batch_X = shuffled_X[k * mini_batch_size : k * 
mini_batch_size + mini_batch_size,:,:,:]
 53         mini_batch_Y = shuffled_Y[k * mini_batch_size : k * 
 mini_batch_size + mini_batch_size,:]

TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.
```

Comment: `num_complete_minibatches = math.floor(m/mini_batch_size)`.  Here is the problem, `math.floor` returns a float

Comment: `for k in range(0, int(num_complete_minibatches))` should do it - alternatively `num_complete_minibatches = int(math.floor( ... ))`

Comment: Also: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) read and use it to debug your problem - the error message was _very_ clear (2me).

Comment: Side note: double slash `//` does floored division, so `int( math.floor(m/mini_batch_size) )` === `int( m // mini_batch_size )`. Furthermore, `for k in xrange( 0, m, mini_batch_size ):` will step ***k*** by mini_batch_size steps, you don't need to do the division at all and you don't need to multiply ***k*** when indexing; makes life that much easier.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answers. However, no advice worked. I'm still getting the same error. What else can I do?